# My userform still show my workbook in macro disable computer

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a question to ask about my userform. I hide my workbook and just userform will visible. It work perfectly in my computer because my computer is macro enabled. But in macro disabled computer, user still can edit my workbook before they enable the macro security warning.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application. Visible=False
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

This is code I used to hide the workbook. Anyone could tell me how can I guide the workbook even in macro disable computer? 
Thank

Answer (score 0):

You could add a sheet telling the user to activate macros, protect it and hide all other sheets. You can also protect the workbook to prevent the user from adding or unhiding sheets. (The latter could also be done by setting them to very hidden).

If you need to show the sheets at some point for user interaction you can hide them again upon saving using the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event.

Comment: I save my userform in 97-2003 format in order to avoid .xlsm format. If I set them in hidden mode, would it coflict with my code above?? Because I have command button to show sheet in my userform with password. There no need to show my workbook to the user in fact I need to avoid  them to look at it.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't access any sheets so it shouldn't be an issue. Did you try what I suggested? Why do you want to avoid .xlsm?

Comment: I thought  about other user which zero knowledge about macro. They probably dont realize about macro security warning and probably dont know what to do. I avoid. xlsm so i dont face this type of problem. But still there have an issue. If I set in hidden mode and its dont have any conflict  with my code, I will give a try later on.

Comment: You can put directions how to enable macros in the "Welcome" sheet. I don't really understand why it would be easier with an xls file instead of xlsm (I think the process of enabling macros is the same?). Even if it's easier I don't think it's worth working in compatibility mode on an old format.

Comment: i thought  with xls fle i would not face this warning issue. Look like im way too far its it? So, there a no easy way to prevent macro security  issue except with enable everytime thr warning pop up?

Comment: If the users enables them and then saves the file it should work from that point on for that file. I don't think that using an old format will change that. If anything, Office will disable features. I think the only way would be to completely enable macros and surely you don't want to recommend that to your users. They only have to learn how to use the file once though so I wouldn't worry much..

Comment: Thank you arcadeprecinct for your opinion.  I think I should run a briefing session before launch my userform.

Comment: set the worksheet to xlveryhidden mode doesnt seem helping much.